# Nested conditional statements logic is wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some verification on my file upload I'm checking for 3 things

1) file was submitted?
2) file type is correct?
3) file size is less than the allowed amount

For some odd reason, my nested conditional statements aren't returning what I expect them to.

I want it to go like:

if user enters a file, check the file type. If the file type passes, check the file size, if the file size passes submit the file to the server.

When I test it in console, if I don't submit a file, the first if block passed but the second fails when I submit both the right file type and wrong file type as well. In addition, i checked the file size block and it fails as well for both cases.

Here is my code and my output on console. For the file type, I already set the state of the true file type in case the user tried to spoof the file.

```js
    async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state);

        // file size bytes in mb
        var fileCheck = Math.floor(Math.log(this.state.fileSize) / Math.log(1024));

        console.log(fileCheck);

        //Check if a uploaded photo was taken.
        if(this.state.fileObject === ''){
            console.log('no file was submitted');
        } else if(this.state.fileType !== 'image/jpeg' || this.state.fileType !== 'image/jpg' || this.state.fileType != 'image/png'){
            // check file type
            console.log('wrong file type');
        } else if(fileCheck >= 2){
            // check file size
            console.log('file is too big');
        }
        else {
            console.log('passed all file checks');
        }
    }
```

Output in console:

[image]

Comment: your use of `!==` and `||` means that first `else if` condition is **always true** ... as  `this.state.fileType` can only have one value, therefore it will always be not equal to at least two of those values

Comment: Specifically, note that `!(a || b)` is not the same thing as `!a || !b`. You're using the latter, but you probably want the former.

Comment: `===` checks if type and the value matches, that's probably the issue, if you only watch the values to match use `==` which seems to be ideal in your case.

Comment: Okay thank you. I might need to get more practice into this.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: No, that won't make any difference when the types of the operands are the same. When the types are different, it then performs complex type coercion, so I wouldn't suggest using that except in rare cases.

Comment: Oh wait, @Jaromanda is right, the second condition is always true.

Comment: I'm always right @ZohirSalak . Except when I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second test here will always evaluate to true:

```
else if(this.state.fileType !== 'image/jpeg' || this.state.fileType !== 'image/jpg' || this.state.fileType != 'image/png'){
```

I recommend checking against an array instead:

```
const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
// ...
else if (!allowedFileTypes.includes(this.state.fileType)) {
  // err, condition failed
}
```

`.includes` is a semi-recent method, if you're supporting ancient browsers and aren't using polyfills, test against `indexOf` instead:

```
const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
// ...
else if (allowedFileTypes.indexOf(this.state.fileType) === -1) {
  // err, condition failed
}
```